# Users get a new password detect forced logout

Tags: rules, users

I want to create a rule:
 
When the user changes the new password, the system should force the user to log out and then use his new password to login.

I know the event to choose after updating an existing user account. 
The next part is to be added in the ELEMENTS PHP source code to detect it?

I have tried this code. It fails, the user can no longer change the new login password.

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id =='user_pass'){
    $form['#submit'][] = 'mytheme_password_redirect';
  }
}
/**
* Redirects user after password reset form is filled
*/
function mytheme_password_redirect(&$form, &$form_state){
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'user/lougout';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All is correct except 'user/lougout' should be 'user/logout'.